# When is a complex subsequence convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

In the complex set of numbers, what sequences have at least one convergent subsequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "complex set"?  Do you mean a set of complex numbers?  Or is it actually the set rather than the numbers that you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\mathbb{C}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$ with additional structure (namely complex multiplication), the answer is provided by the [Bolzanon-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

That is, every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. The proof goes exactly as in the real case.

Answer (score 0):

By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, every bounded complex sequence has at least one convergent subsequence.